# Make PhpStorm stop automatically closing tabs

Tags: php, phpstorm

In PhpStorm once you open several tabs they start disappearing automatically. How to turn that setting off?

Don't see a setting for this anywhere.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

File > Settings > Editor > General > Editor Tabs

Under the "Tab closing policy" change **tab limit** to a bigger number.

[image]

Comment: Now they call it Preferences instead of settings. Thanks for your answer it helped me a lot.

Comment: Works in Webstorm too

Comment: It is bad feature default value... I had 10! by default :( Now it works better, thanks!

Comment: Also super annoying that it always closes deleted files.. which can't be turned off!! So working with multiple branches where different files exists is a headache :< sublime prompts at least if it should close it or not..

Comment: This is a "bug" they call a feature. And nobody has fixed it yet (removed that closing policy altogether). When I start PhpStorm it immediately eats almost 2GB of RAM, no matter how many tabs I have opened!

Comment: What an absolutely useless "feature". They make some bizarre design decisions about their IDEs, which wouldn't be too bad if they gave us the option to disable them.

Comment: I thought it was me was going crazy and "accidentally" closing tabs. What a stupid feature, it should at the very least give you a warning the 1st time you run into the 10 tab limit and ask you what to do.

Comment: And the worst thing - it doesn't warn you that it will start to close tabs. I was searching in the directly and opening files them from the find files - only to found only 10 files in the tabs. And I was sure that there was more! It took me some time to realize what is going on! The JetBrains IDEs are generally good - but this is such frustrating feature/bug that make me question their value!